# List of available events for wp.media

Tags: media-library, media-modal

Is there a list of available events for wp.media object?
By doing some googling, I managed to find following events:
for **wp.media.view.Modal.prototype**: **open**, **ready** - they are triggered, when user opens the Modal window.

The reason why I need this list is that I want to insert a select box on the right side, when user clicks an item on the Insert Media window. This select has to be formatted with [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) library, but since the Backbone view is loaded only on user interaction, I need to know, on which event to initialize [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Please add other events in your answers.

Answer (score 10):

If you're still looking for this kind of answer, one way of figuring out what is firing is by entering this in your browser console and using the media modal:

`wp.media.frame.on('all', function(e) { console.log(e); });`

Comment: Thanks for this @thumbson Very helpful. Do you know how to listen to the events that create modals themselves?

Comment: Thanks @thumbson, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can install     the plugin [WordPress Media Javascript Guide](https://github.com/ericandrewlewis/wp-media-javascript-guide). It explains with screenshots and examples the must use method of the wp.media object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This guide is definitely the best information source about wp.media that ir currently available in the internet, but it is still very far from being complete. For example, I wasn't able to find there events that I mentioned in the question.