# List of JS Events for Widgets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, widgets, events

Does anyone know if there's a list of all JavaScript `events` for [widgets](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/)? I know there are other lists (e.g. [Woocommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/352171/51546); [`wp.media`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/319466/51546)) but I'm looking for one specifically for [widgets](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets%20API).

It took me a bit of time to find events like `widget-updated` and `widget-added` but are there more than just those two?

Any advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!